# how to make a client/server turn-based java game playable in two different computers

Tags: java, network-programming

I've been making a turn based multi-player(two player actually) in Java. I've made it playable for two players on the same device, and everything...

I have a multi-threaded serverClass controlling the two instances of the clientClass and it is using sockets to communicate on the same machine.

Now, I'm wondering how to make it playable over two different systems in the network?

Comment: sockets can also be used to communicate between two machines on the same network...

Comment: I'm completely a noob in networking. Will it work in an ad-hoc network?
Thanks

Comment: As long as the client knows the server's address and the server is listening and both are connected..It will work

Comment: Ad hoc means there is no client or server. Any node can initiate the communication and as long as the destination can receive and identify that it's meant for him, it would work

Answer (score 0):

In your Client you can use

```
InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.232");
```

where 192.168.1.232 is your Server IP address. When you connect via Adhoc or LAN it would be better if you give your server a static IP so that it does not change.
If you are using TCP the use

```
new Socket("192.168.1.232", port);
```